# canDeactive | observable keeps its initial value

Tags: angular, angular-routing, candeactivate

- Example seen by [this example](http://techiediaries.com/angular-candeactivate)

This is my canDeactivate Guard:

```
export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate, 
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
  state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }   
}
```

This is how i call it in Routing for HomeComponent:

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]},
```

In MyService, i have this Subject:

```
private backButtonEnabled = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
currentBackButtonEnabled = this.backButtonEnabled.asObservable();

changeCurrentBackButtonEnabled(goBack: boolean){
  this.backButtonEnabled.next(goBack);
}
```

In another component, the FiltersComponent, i have this function:

```
openFilters() {
  ...
  this.myService.changeCurrentBackButtonEnabled(false);
}
```

In HomeComponent, i call the canDeactivate like this:

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean | Promise<boolean> {
  this.myService.currentBackButtonEnabled.subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res) //ALWAYS TRUE
  })
  return this.myService.currentBackButtonEnabled;
}
```

In appModule:

...

```
  providers: [
    CanDeactivateGuard,
    MyService
  ],
```

> Problem statement:

The **currentBackButtonEnabled is always true**, even when the user (click) on openFilters() function, where the currentBackButtonEnabled  turns to false

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your code, but in your guard

```
return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
```

You can't have a variable and a function of the same name in a type script class / Angular Component Class.  As such, this line checks for the existence of `canActivate`--which is always true; because you defined a function by that name on that component.

If `component.canDeactivate()` exists, then it is executed.

And based on your code:

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean | Promise<boolean> {
  return this.service.currentBackButtonEnabled;
}
```

If the `canActivate()` method is returning an Observable or Promise then as long as that value is defined, it will be seen as true from a Boolean perspective.

The only situation where this code will return false is if `canDeactivate()` returns a boolean value of false.  If you want to get the results from an Observable or Promise you have to subscribe to it.

Comment: Hello! the code is taken by this example: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-candeactivate/ . Also, if i initialize the backButtonEnabled Observable like this: private backButtonEnabled = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(FALSE); then, it always returns false

Comment: You may have to put together a runnable sample to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the observable to get its new values.

```
this.guardService.canDeactivate().pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        this.logger.error('Observable error', err);
        throw err;
      })
    )
      .subscribe((newState) => { // do something }
      });
```

Also you should inject your service into components, and then broadcast events to the components that should act upon its changes, not the other way around.